# Rails 4: Should I preload relations in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

Say I am displaying all of the users their posts as shown below.

```
<% @users do |user| %>
    <div><%= user.name %> : </div>
    <% user.posts.each do |post| %>
        <div><%= post.title %></div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Is it better to load the posts (specifically for database speed) beforehand in the controller?

```
@users = User.includes(:posts)
```

or is it better to just fetch the users and load the post in the view?

```
@users = User.all
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you iterate through a collection and access a child assocations this creates what is called a N+1 query issue where each record will create a separate database query.

If a single request ends up using 100 database queries your server will grind to a halt in no time.

```
<% @users do |user| %>
    <div><%= user.name %> : </div>
    <!--  This line will create a N+1 query -->
    <% user.posts.each do |post| %>
        <div><%= post.title %></div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So yes - preloading associations is necessary to build applications that scale (or even work). [ActiveRecord provides several methods such as  `.includes`, `.preload`, `.eager_load`, `.join`](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html) and [`.left_outer_joins`](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/24/support-for-left-outer-joins-in-rails-5.html) (Rails 5) that each give different results and are good for different use cases.

Comment: Thank you very much that makes sense